# How to import locally in a proper way in PyCharm OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-import

Here's how the directory looks like

```
├── Caches
│   ├── 11\ Centroids\ representing\ relative\ anchor\ sizes..png
│   ├── 9\ Centroids\ representing\ relative\ anchor\ sizes..png
│   ├── Generated\ anchors\ relative\ to\ sample\ image\ size.png
│   ├── Relative\ width\ and\ height\ for\ 10107\ boxes..png
│   └── data_set_labels.csv
├── Config
│   ├── feature_map.py
│   ├── set_annotation_conf.py
│   └── voc_conf.json
├── Helpers
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── annotation_parsers.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── visual_tools.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── anchors.py
│   ├── annotation_parsers.py
│   ├── dataset_handlers.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── visual_tools.py
├── README.md
├── sample_img.png
└── structure_requirements.txt
```

in `dataset_handlers.py` I need to import the following:

```
from ..Config.feature_map import get_feature_map
```

and in `anchors.py` I need to import the following:

```
from .visual_tools import visualization_wrapper
```

Both imports do resolve in PyCharm or in other words do not have syntax errors however when are run they give the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

If I do this:

```
from visual_tools import visualization_wrapper
```

the name `visual_tools` is unresolved however it runs without errors and it imports the requested things

How to be able to make relative imports `from .some_module import something` without getting errors and being resolved without marking the directory as sources root.

Comment: What's against a __init__.py in both directories (Config & Helpers)? It helps you at these stages quite a lot - at least in my opinion

Comment: the `__init__` in both folders gives the same error while attempting relative imports